# Init Phone Number Package in Flutter Throw Null Value When Sending OTP using Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send OTP when user select country code and enter phonenumber and when click on onTap function than OTP have to send, but it gives an error :

> "PlatformException(error, The given phoneNumber is empty. Please set a
> non-empty phone number with
> #setPhoneNumber(), null, null)"

Variables declarations -

```
final TextEditingController phonecontroller = TextEditingController();
    PhoneNumber number = PhoneNumber(isoCode: 'IN');
```

Init Phone Number Field :----

```
Row(
  //PhoneNumberField
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Animate(
      effects: const [
        FadeEffect(delay: Duration(milliseconds: 3000)),
        SlideEffect()
      ],
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 18, vertical: 5),
        child: SizedBox(
          width: 350,
          height: 50,
          child: Container(
            //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(22),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
              border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.10)),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0Xffeeeeee),
                  blurRadius: 1,
                  offset: Offset(0, 1),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 12),
                  child: InternationalPhoneNumberInput(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: AppColor.textColor),
                    hintText: 'Phone Number',
                    initialValue: number,
                    selectorConfig: const SelectorConfig(
                        selectorType: PhoneInputSelectorType
                            .BOTTOM_SHEET),
                    onInputChanged: (PhoneNumber number) {
                      print(number.phoneNumber);
                    },
                    onInputValidated: (bool value) {
                      print(value);
                    },
                    ignoreBlank: false,
                    textFieldController: phonecontroller,
                    formatInput: true,
                    cursorColor: Colors.black,
                    inputDecoration: const InputDecoration(
                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(
                          bottom: 15, left: 0),
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  left: 97,
                  top: 2,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 45,
                    width: 1,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.13),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),

    const SizedBox(
      height: 10,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Submit Button Code :---------

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        verificationCompleted:
            (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {},
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException ex) {},
        codeSent:
            (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => OtpVerify(
                  verificationId: verificationId,
                ),
              ));
        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout:
            (String verificationId) {},
        phoneNumber: phonecontroller.text.toString());
    // print(number);
    //submitForm();
    // Navigator.push(
    //   context,
    //   PageTransition(
    //     duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    //     type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
    //     child: GetEmail(),
    //   ),
    // );

    //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute87(builder: (context) => OtpVerify(),));
  },
  child: Container(
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color:
          AppColor.mainColor, // Button background color
    ),
    child: const Icon(
      Icons.arrow_forward,
      color: Colors.white, // Icon color
      size: 30,
    ),
  ),
),
```